# How do I change all occurrences of "Sí" into "Yes" in my data set?

Tags: r

```
data[data == 'Sí'] <- 'Yes'
```

My code yields the error:
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: You may need to subset  only character columns and assign i.e. `i1 <- sapply(MW_all, is.character); MW_all[i1][MW_all[i1] == 'Si'] <- "Yes"`

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output. See how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Is `data` a data frame? Or a vector? If it's a data frame, the code you have would replace values throughout the data frame, rather than just within one column

Comment: Sounds like `data` is actually an R date-time vector.

Answer (score 0):

first create a function:

```
findSi <- function(vector1) { vector1[vector1=='Si'] <- 'Yes'}
```

then, apply it by columns

```
apply(df,2,findSi)
```

**assuming youir df is the name of your dataframe